Is there any option to automate a google image search to text to save into a single file?
I have the said workflow. I opened a PDF (image pages, not text, language is Bengali), right click on the page, clicked on search images with google. then clicked on text on the side bar, then click on select all text, then on copy text. and I created a docs.new file, and pasted over there.
this is a manual task to convert a Bengali PDF to text, and later I create a epub file.
Is there any way I can automate this / in any program like python?
I tried the manual tasks, and wanted to automate, as this is a lengthy task, when the PDF is 500 pages.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
